# make query ManyToMany in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

in sqlalchemy,the models like this:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(IdDataType, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50))
class Group(Base):
    id = Column(IdDataType, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50))
    members = relationship('User', secondary='group_members', backref='memeber_groups')

group_members = Table('group_members', Base.metadata,
    Column('group_id', IdDataType, ForeignKey('group.id')),
    Column('user_id', IdDataType, ForeignKey('user.id')),
    Column('join_time', DateTime, default=datetime.now)
)
```

`User` and `Group` is manytomany relaionship, now I want to find `count(users)` where `group.id=3` and the `join_time` is `between now and preivew week` ,how to make this SQL in sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an association object than a direct many-to-many, so I'd set it up like this instead:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False, unique=True)


class Group(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False, unique=True)


class Membership(Base):
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id), primary_key=True)
    joined_on = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow, server_default=func.current_timestamp())

    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('memberships', collection_class=set))
    group = relationship(Group, backref=backref('memberships', collection_class=set))


User.groups = association_proxy('memberships', 'group')
Group.users = association_proxy('memberships', 'user')
```

The query would look like this:

```
session.query(Membership.user_id).filter(Membership.group_id == 3, Membership.joined_on.between(previous, now)).count()
```